# What is the relation between the speed of various components of a mixture, and their respective Retardation Factors in adsorption chromatography?

Tags: chromatography

Consider two components, I and II, of a mixture which is subject to adsorption column chromatography. Let I have higher adsorption than II.

I know that Retardation Factor ($R_f$) of component II will be higher than that of I. Which component will move down the column at a faster speed? Is the speed of a component in chromatography related to its $R_f$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If I has really higher adsorption, it is the one retarded more, not the II.

Chromatography, in a basic terms, separates components of a mixture according to their adsorption/desorption equilibrium. If a compound does not even adsorp, it will come with solvent front and will be fastest. If a compound adsorp so much that become effectively immobile, it may not even be seen at the end.

You need to think that chemical will move when in mobile phase, when it is adsorped, it will be immobile so its change of position in unit time will decrease as much as it adsorps.

Comment: But if I is adsorbed more then it will travel less distance than II. $R_f$ is defined as ratio of distance travelled by component to distance travelled by solvent, so II will travel more distance and will have a higher $R_f$

Comment: So even though $R_f$ of II is more, will it be faster?

Comment: Yes, higher retardation factor, faster compound. I should give the first sentence as II and I not in I and II order, but nevertheless you got the point.